# Nodejs array not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to read in from a text file and store them in a array of my Lease class. If I console.log() from inside the my final loop it will print the loop in its current state for each iterration. But if I move the console.log outside the loop it prints an empty array.

#### working as expected

```
const readline = require('readline'),
  fs = require('fs');

function Lease(renter, unit) {
  this.unit = unit;
  this.renter = renter;
}

var list = [];

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('input.txt'),
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', function(line) {
  var values = line.split(' - ');
  list.push(new Lease(values[0], values[1]));
  console.log(list);
});
```

#### printing empty array

```
const readline = require('readline'),
  fs = require('fs');

function Lease(renter, unit) {
  this.unit = unit;
  this.renter = renter;
}

var list = [];

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('input.txt'),
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', function(line) {
  var values = line.split(' - ');
  list.push(new Lease(values[0], values[1]));
});

console.log(list);
```

Comment: In your second version, `console.log` is executed before anything is added to the array.

Comment: Yes, because by the time you printed `list`, there was no update from `readline` module. Only when the `line` event occurs you will get data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version, the `console.log()` is in the callback function, it will be executed when the callback function is invoked.

However, in the second version, the `console.log()` will be called before the callback function of `on.('line'` executed...

The callback function is *Async*, it won't be executed until current stack is empty...

Comment: So how can I get it to print the array only after all lines have been processed?

Comment: Well, how do you know when all the lines are processed? You could listen for `close`, or get the user to type something specific (in interactive version)...

Comment: Thanks @Amadan listening for on.close worked

Comment: @AntarrByrd, `Amadan` has given you the right direction...